# Showing $x \sin x$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $x\sin x$ is not bounded above (as $x \to \infty$)? It's not strictly increasing, but it oscillates with greater and greater amplitude - is there a way to make this rigorous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** If $n\in\mathbb N$, what is $\left(2\pi n+\frac\pi2\right)\sin\left(2\pi n+\frac\pi2\right)$?

Comment: It's $2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2} > 2\pi n > n$, so that works. Thanks.